# Trying to get the total to generate from quantity and price

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been working on this for a little longer then needed, but I can't find what is going wrong here. I think I've looked at it way too long. I need to get the items to add up after quantity is add to the form.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid container-cart">

    <div class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://myurl.com/image.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="">Title</h3>
                <p class="">Description</p>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <p class="lead">
                            <span id="item-price">100</span>
                            <span class="price-integer">
                                <input type="hidden" value="100">
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <span>Quantity</span>
                        <input type="text" name="" id="quantity" class="stored quantity" autocomplete="off" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <input type="text" name="base-total" id="base-total" class="stored readonly base-total" value="" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="span6">
    Total: 
    <span class="total-cart">
         <input type="text" name="total-cart" id="total-cart" class="stored readonly" value="" disabled="disabled">
    </span>
</div>
```

**Here is my JS**

```
$('.quantity').on('keyup', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".container-cart").each(function(i,o){

        total = parseInt($(o).find(".quantity input").val(), 10) * parseInt($(o).find(".price-integer input").val(), 10);
        if(!isNaN(total) /*&& total.length!=0**/) {
            $(o).find(".base-total").val(total);
            sum += total;
        }
    });
    $("#total-cart").val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you typed a wrong selector, it's the `.quantity input`, the `.quantity` is an input, so it won't have any children, maybe you want to mean the `input.quantity` which means finding the `input` having class `quantity`.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DkYEW/)

Comment: See, I was looking at this way too long haha! That is exactly what I meant to do is `input.quantity`. Thanks!!